# How to detect the position of image when it stops spinning?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I want to create a wheel control for my school project using Visual studios 2012.
What I have right now is the image and it is able to rotate when I click a button and stop at random positions.
However, I am not sure how to detect the position when the image stops spinning.
This is the spin button event where the image spins when I click the button.

```
 private void SpinBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var ease = new PowerEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };

            Random rng = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
            //DoubleAnimation(FromValue. ToValue, Duration)
            DoubleAnimation myanimation = new DoubleAnimation
                    (0, rng.Next(360,720), new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)));

            //Adding Power ease to the animation
            myanimation.EasingFunction = ease;

            RotateTransform rotate = new RotateTransform();

            img.RenderTransform = rotate;
            img.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
            rotate.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, myanimation);


        }
```

How do I detect the position of the image (where the pointer points) once it stops spinning? So that when the pointer is pointing to that object, I can drag and drop the words into the specific textbox.

Refer to [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1kru4kx8bqz5vo/Picture1.png?dl=0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need to know where the image(pointer) points,just calculate the spinning degree.

```
double degree = rng.Next(360, 720);
DoubleAnimation myanimation = new DoubleAnimation
                (0, degree, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)));
double result_degree = degree % 360;
```

now, you can get the target object with result_degree .

for example:

you have 12 objects in a circle like a clock,so the 1st object's degree is 0 to 29, 2nd is 30 to 59....

or you can set objects' degree by yourself, 1st is 0 to 9, 2nd is 10 to 39...

**about drag and drop:**

I give you a simple example:

```
 <Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="tbResult" HorizontalAlignment="Left" AllowDrop="True" Height="23" Margin="416,245,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

    <TextBlock x:Name="tb1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MouseLeftButtonDown="MyMouseLeftButtonDown" Margin="280,210,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="ob1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    <TextBlock x:Name="tb2" IsEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MouseLeftButtonDown="MyMouseLeftButtonDown" Margin="280,245,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="ob2" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tb3" IsEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  MouseLeftButtonDown="MyMouseLeftButtonDown" Margin="280,281,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="ob3" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>



private void MyMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock tb = sender as TextBlock ;
        if(tb != null && tb.IsEnabled == true)
        {
            switch(tb.Name)
            {
                case "tb1" :
                    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(tb1, tb1.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy);
                    break;
                case "tb2":
                    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(tb2, tb2.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy);
                    break;
                case "tb3":
                    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(tb3, tb3.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy);
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
```

when you get result_degree and know which object is selected, set it's `IsEnable = true` and others  `IsEnable = false` , set TextBox's `AllowDrop = true`.in this example, just allow user drag `ob1`.

Comment: how to I allow user to just drag the word to the specific textbox for the image that the pointer is pointing?

Comment: I get my textbox and words from my database. And the textbox is according to the number of words I get. So do I still use the same method as you suggested above?

Comment: @Hasbi I just give you a example, do not limited by it. But in this case, I advice you to use the same method.Because TextBlocks are created dynamicly,regist the same MouseLeftButtonDown Event to them is conveniently.